# Using tabular(){tables: How to define a function (for p value, e.g.) for multiple samplings?

Tags: r, plyr, tabular, multisampling

I often have to produce tables containing, e.g., mean, sd, and the result of a simple test. To have a reproducable and shareable workflow, I tried to do this with `tables::tabular` . 
(See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378482/r-how-can-i-create-a-table-with-mean-and-sd-according-to-experimental-group-alo/9385405#9385405) on how to include a test as a function.)

This works:

```
nicetable <- tabular(sampling~treatment*var1*(mean+sd), data=tab)
```

However, I failed to define a function for, e.g., a paired Wilcoxon signed rank test to compare treatments in a multiple sampling case: it seems like I'm failing to pass the right arguments or data to the function.

Can anybody who is less stupid than myself help out?

Here's some data for reproducibility, if you care:

```
structure(list(plot = structure(c(6L, 9L, 6L, 9L, 6L, 9L, 6L, 
9L, 12L, 15L, 12L, 15L, 12L, 15L, 12L, 15L, 5L, 16L, 5L, 16L, 
5L, 16L, 5L, 16L, 8L, 17L, 8L, 17L, 8L, 17L, 8L, 17L, 4L, 10L, 
4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 2L, 11L, 2L, 11L, 2L, 11L, 2L, 11L, 
3L, 13L, 3L, 13L, 3L, 13L, 3L, 13L, 1L, 14L, 1L, 14L, 1L, 14L, 
1L, 14L, 24L, 19L, 24L, 19L, 24L, 19L, 24L, 19L, 22L, 23L, 22L, 
23L, 22L, 23L, 22L, 23L, 20L, 21L, 20L, 21L, 20L, 21L, 20L, 21L, 
7L, 18L, 7L, 18L, 7L, 18L, 7L, 18L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24"), class = "factor"), 
    sampling = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), pairs = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), .Label = c("pair_1", 
    "pair_10", "pair_11", "pair_12", "pair_2", "pair_3", "pair_4", 
    "pair_5", "pair_6", "pair_7", "pair_8", "pair_9"), class = "factor"), 
    treatment = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
    "B"), class = "factor"), var1 = c(4, 6, 21, 11, 6, 11, 21, 
    16, 2, 5, 18, 18, 8, 5, 26, 24, 0, 4, 28, 26, 7, 11, 20, 
    29, 1, 4, 17, 28, 20, 11, 20, 24, 11, 8, 19, 15, 11, 10, 
    16, 17, 7, 4, 18, 21, 6, 6, 18, 16, 7, 2, 17, 15, 3, 12, 
    18, 26, 8, 5, 23, 17, 9, 8, 24, 20, 7, 7, 1, 17, 9, 10, 7, 
    0, 0, 5, 18, 0, 8, 10, 15, 17, 5, 7, 24, 19, 13, 8, 20, 17, 
    1, 2, 22, 19, 6, 8, 17, 13), var2 = c(0.531857406453951, 
    0.99147016935005, 0.978386084625517, 0.547701177005542, 0.557590884845267, 
    0.986951076487171, 0.562417675727868, 0.986951076487171, 
    0.483984835736487, 0.726909676798849, 0.388579012270421, 
    0.745553604701919, 0.465094116634877, 0.726909676798849, 
    0.488003757207879, 0.557184406817338, 0.701676487711027, 
    0.869080260649975, 0.720173845681177, 0.750917673793786, 
    0.755303408639525, 0.506987878760014, 0.686245881868453, 
    0.60763119427203, 0.548453587721443, 0.703832816328718, 0.412731402996848, 
    0.717973047643672, 0.550210159561483, 0.671791216125084, 
    0.361548563337832, 0.606668062640702, 0.518806412571116, 
    0.742554357381421, 0.507677339941509, 0.923200219631054, 
    0.341071242549443, 0.681636160803754, 0.384435345144425, 
    0.61998338971563, 0.557812388143911, 0.632317782224629, 0.603677751166685, 
    0.632317782224629, 0.624604514381939, 0.623183042284434, 
    0.589665731283708, 0.338738325837909, 0.448751068565499, 
    0.620695986589587, 0.412147458001507, 0.354008373981433, 
    0.444023865279733, 0.366742726110414, 0.368307839974067, 
    0.338054566392881, 0.492950438718815, 0.722825772176568, 
    0.529502336899605, 0.834207208644564, 0.523569852219379, 
    0.834207208644564, 0.591655754114154, 0.725359004030846, 
    0.604856790039767, 0.787389376103932, 0.491331714116263, 
    0.828838159960298, 0.506594233666576, 0.75537998521935, 0.477785779781003, 
    0.925304881641062, 0.425400499022199, 0.537980402016095, 
    0.443113792876767, 0.991210220561304, 0.366372451776005, 
    0.585051630458758, 0.363869227771921, 0.67007984346546, 0.37054162796269, 
    0.574771389575503, 0.446535654066238, 0.700306153200489, 
    0.358793598876081, 0.309159322200134, 0.372983177758783, 
    0.353384010493424, 0.492456412584678, 0.359873708654463, 
    0.436447650900556, 0.591291884661869, 0.436447650900556, 
    0.603360031882414, 0.453002902987777, 0.370462648444931)), .Names = c("plot", 
"sampling", "pairs", "treatment", "var1", "var2"), row.names = c(NA, 
96L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Possibly you need to write `sampling~I(wilcox_function(treatment))...` to get your function into the `formula` format (I just threw in a fake function name there for an example).

Answer (score 2):

It might help if you showed what syntax you would like to be able to use and what you would like the output to look like.  The problem with how `tabular` currently works is that it passes a single vector (the subset of the data column being processed corresponding to the current cell of the table) to the summary function, and no other arguments.  But `Wilcox.test` and other testing functions need multiple arguments that `tabular` currently has no way of passing along.

The possibility of computing percentages (using `Percent` in the formula) has been added, so a feature request to the author/maintainer may yield a similar possibility for tests in the future, but this will be much more complicated with all the possible arguments to be passed in.

You can create your own function with the extra arguments hard coded in as in the previous answer, but this could cause difficulty with trying to maintain a reproducible and sharable workflow.

Another option is to pre compute the p-value and any other summaries of interest and attach them to the data frame, then just include a term in the formula to grab the 1st element of the computed column(s).  Here is an example that uses `ddply` to do the computations and return an augmented data frame, then calls `tabular` to display:

```
library(plyr)

tab2 <- ddply(tab, .(sampling), function(df) {
    x <- df$var1
    g <- df$treatment
    df$P.value <- wilcox.test(x[g=='A'], x[g=='B'], paired=TRUE)$p.value
    df$diff <- x[g=='A'] - x[g=='B']
    df
})

` ` <- function(x) x[1]

tabular(sampling ~ treatment*var1*(mean+sd) + 
     ` `*diff +(Wilcoxon = ` `*P.value), data=tab2)
```

It is not as nice as being able to just add a term to the formula for `tabular`, but you can control exactly what you want computed, then displayed.